Gutenberg Custom Block Styles Are Loaded After Footer Causing FOUC and CLS
I'm facing an issue with my custom Gutenberg block plugin, and I could really use your expertise.
I am developing a plugin that registers multiple blocks. All of them are dynamic blocks that use render.php. Each block has its own CSS file, and I want the styles to load efficiently in the to avoid Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) and Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS). Strangely, only the CSS for blocks that are not present on the page are being correctly loaded in the <head>. The CSS for blocks that are used on the page are being appended after the footer, causing noticeable layout shifts during page load and I suspect also affect my loading speed negatively. I assume it has something to do with the render_callback cycle or something related.
Initially, I figured that WordPress might be loading CSS in the footer because it doesn’t know which blocks are used until the content is rendered. Therefore, I tried several approaches to force the CSS to load earlier:

Enqueuing CSS in wp_enqueue_scripts: I manually registered and enqueued all block styles during the wp_enqueue_scripts action to force them into the . This did not work—the styles were still appended after the footer.

Using register_block_type with style Parameter: I registered each block with its associated CSS file using the 'style' parameter in register_block_type. However, the same issue persisted—styles for blocks on the page still ended up after the footer.

Setting should_load_separate_core_block_assets Filter to true: I enabled this filter to ensure WordPress loads styles selectively, but the problem remains. It seems like the dynamic rendering of blocks might still be interfering with the timing of the CSS enqueuing.


What I Need Help With:

Is there a way to ensure the CSS for blocks present on the page is loaded in the instead of the footer, without disrupting the block rendering lifecycle?

Could this behavior be linked to how dynamic blocks or render callbacks interact with the block assets loading process?

Is there a known solution or pattern for this issue that ensures both efficient CSS loading and correct rendering of dynamic blocks?


Below is a sanitized version of my plugin’s PHP file:
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name:       Custom Blocks
 * Description:       Custom Gutenberg blocks plugin.
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * Text Domain:       custom-blocks
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

function register_custom_blocks() {
    $blocks = [
        'block-1', 'block-2', 'block-3', // Example block slugs.
    ];

    foreach ($blocks as $block) {
        $style_path = __DIR__ . "/build/$block/style.css";
        
        if (file_exists($style_path)) {
            wp_register_style(
                "custom-$block-style",
                plugins_url("build/$block/style.css", __FILE__),
                [],
                filemtime($style_path),
                'all'
            );
            wp_enqueue_style("custom-$block-style");
        }

        register_block_type(__DIR__ . "/build/$block");
    }
}
add_action('init', 'register_custom_blocks');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_register_script('custom-inline', '', [], false, false);
    $loadScripts = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/utils/loadScript.js');
    
    if ($loadScripts !== false) {
        wp_add_inline_script('custom-inline', $loadScripts);
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-inline');
}, 0);

add_filter('should_load_separate_core_block_assets', '__return_true');

Thank you very much in advance for any help or guidance. I look forward to hearing your thoughts and suggestions! 

This is a common issue when dealing with Gutenberg blocks, especially dynamic ones. Here are some suggestions to tackle the Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) and Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) you're experiencing:
Load Styles Properly in the : It seems that the key issue is the styles being loaded too late in the lifecycle. To ensure CSS for dynamic blocks loads early in the , try:
Use the style parameter in register_block_type effectively: Make sure the style parameter is being correctly used when you register the block. In your code, you’re enqueuing the styles separately via wp_enqueue_style(), which means they get enqueued globally and only when the block is rendered. To avoid this, try ensuring the CSS is associated with the block registration itself. Example:
register_block_type(__DIR__ . "/build/$block", [
    'style' => "custom-$block-style",  // Add this line to link the CSS with the block.
]);

Enqueue Styles on wp_enqueue_scripts with Conditions: To ensure the styles are included in the , you can manually enqueue them with a conditional check to see if the block is present on the page. Here's how you might do it:
function enqueue_block_styles_in_head() {
    if (has_block('namespace/block-1')) {
        wp_enqueue_style("custom-block-1-style");
    }
    if (has_block('namespace/block-2')) {
        wp_enqueue_style("custom-block-2-style");
    }
    // Repeat for other blocks.
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_block_styles_in_head', 1);

The has_block() function helps load the styles only when the relevant block is used on the page, ensuring they load in the  section. The action priority 1 helps ensure they are loaded early.
Disable Footer Loading for Dynamic Block Styles: WordPress tends to load some block styles in the footer when using dynamic rendering due to dependencies that may not be known until runtime. By leveraging the style property as above, WordPress should load the styles inline with the block or in the head.
Add Inline Styles via Render Callback: For dynamic blocks, you can manually include inline styles directly in the render callback of your block. Though this might increase page size slightly, it prevents FOUC:
function render_custom_block($attributes, $content) {
    wp_enqueue_style("custom-block-1-style"); // Enqueue the styles directly here.
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="custom-block">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

This approach makes sure the CSS is loaded immediately when the block renders.
Set Load Priority and Dependencies Correctly: You may need to adjust the $deps array in wp_register_style() if your stylesheets depend on any core block styles. Make sure the styles are not loading after other dependent stylesheets by adding necessary dependencies, such as 'wp-block-library'.
Use Block Asset Filter Hooks: There’s a filter hook called block_assets that lets you enqueue assets for blocks before the footer is loaded:
add_action('enqueue_block_assets', function() {
    if (is_singular() && has_block('namespace/block-1')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-block-1-style');
    }
    // Repeat for other blocks.
});

Separate Block Editor and Frontend Styles: Make sure that the styles specific to the editor are separated from the front-end styles by using editor_style and style when registering the block:
register_block_type(__DIR__ . "/build/$block", [
    'style' => "custom-$block-style", // Frontend style.
    'editor_style' => "custom-$block-editor-style", // Editor style.
]);

This issue can indeed be related to how dynamic blocks interact with the block rendering lifecycle, but by making the styles load as early as possible and linking them properly to the block registration, you can reduce layout shifts and improve load speed.
Let me know if these suggestions help or if you need more guidance!
